# Other ways of kickstarting Spring Boot instead of SpringApplication.run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am just curious of there are other ways to run or kickstart a Spring Boot application aside from using SpringApplication.run() method. For example, can AnnotationConfigApplicationContext start the application and why? Can you list some other ways and differentiate it.

Comment: You can do what the `run()` method does, but why would you want to? Anyway, have a look at the source code of `run()`. It's very easy to do if you use a good IDE, and if you're not using a good IDE *(would be dumb not to)*, you can also see the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L292) online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before spring boot in the core, we need to deal with application context
then from there, we have to take the next running service class bean than call that method.

There also have two ways for XmlBaseConfiguration or AnnotationBaseConfiguration

```
public class XmlBaseConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "META-INF/spring-context.xml");
        HelloWorld hw = (HelloWorld) appContext.getBean("helloWorld");

        String output = hw.getValueFromContext("strHelloWorld");
        System.out.print(output);
    }
}
```

OR

```
public class AnnotationBaseConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Configuration.class); 
        HelloWorld hw = (HelloWorld) appContext.getBean("helloWorld");

        String output = hw.getValueFromContext("strHelloWorld");
        System.out.print(output);
    }
}
```